# jQuery ajax call execute function after complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am developing a mobile app. I use ajax calls to receive data from a webserver with this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    data: {
        name: 'Chad'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.posts, function(i, post) {
            $.mobile.notesdb.transaction(function(t) {
                t.executeSql('INSERT into bill (barcode, buildingcode, buildingaddress, flatname, flatdescription, entryseason, period, amount, pastpayments, todaypayments, receiptno) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);',
                    [post.Id, post.Code, post.Address, post.Name, post.Description, post.EntrySeason, post.Period, post.Revenue, post.PastPayments, post.todaypayments, post.receiptno],
                    //$.mobile.changePage('#page3', 'slide', false, true),  
                    null);
            });
        });
    },
    complete: function() {
        test = 1;
    }
});
```

I want the `complete` function to be executed after all data inserted to SQLite...

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to pick up an event from sqlite, not from your AJAX call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `complete` callback should be in your `executeSql` function. `executeSql` should accept three arguments:

```
var sqlString = 'INSERT into bill (barcode, buildingcode, buildingaddress, flatname, flatdescription, entryseason, period, amount, pastpayments, todaypayments, receiptno) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);';
var sqlValues = [post.Id, post.Code, post.Address, post.Name, post.Description, post.EntrySeason, post.Period, post.Revenue, post.PastPayments, post.todaypayments, post.receiptno];
var callback = function(){ test = 1; }
executeSql(sqlString, sqlValues, callback);
```

You should edit your `executeSql` function and make it accept a third argument, and end the function with `callback();`.

On another note, isn't passing SQL queries like this a security issue? Like, a major one?

Comment: is there a way to execute callback once??? because the callback function executed for each sqlite insert

Comment: I don't see how, since your SQL is executed asynchronously. You could count how many callbacks are returned, and execute a function when the numbers of callbacks returned equals the number of requests sent.